# Roles with laravel 5, how to allow only admin access to some root

Tags: php, laravel-5

I follow this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmJYVhG6UzM Currently I can check in my blade if user is a admin or not like this:

```
{{ Auth::user()->roles->toArray()[0]['role'] }}
HI ADMIN
@endif
```

How can I make my route only available for admin user?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to create a middleware for your route.

Use: `php artisan make:middleware AdminMiddleware`.

You will find in your middleware folder a new file with this name.

Put your logic in your middleware, e.g.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::check())
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
    else
    {
        return view('auth.login')->withErrors('You are not logged in');
    }

}
```

Once you have done your logic in your middleware, you can either call it in the route or make the middleware apply to all routes.

If you want to add it to all routes, go to `Kernel.php` and add it to the `$middleware` array, e.g.

```
protected $middleware = [
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
    'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
    'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
    'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
    'App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware',
];
```

If you want to add it to specific routes only, add it to the `$routeMiddleware` variable and add the alias to the route. E.g.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
    'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
    'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
    'admin' => 'App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware',
];
```

You can then add it to a route, as a filter, e.g.

```
Route::get('admin/profile', ['middleware' => 'admin', function()
{

}]);
```

For additional info visit the docs:

http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware

**EDIT**

An improvement on this would be to use variadic functions which was introduced in PHP 5.6

http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php

Instead of having to make a middleware for each permission set you can do the following

PermissionMiddleware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use \App\Models\Role;
class PermissionMiddleware
{
    // Pass parameters to this middleware
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$permitted_roles)
    {

        //Get a users role
        $role = new Role;
        $role_name = $role->getUserRoleByName();
        foreach($permitted_roles as $permitted_role) {
            if($permitted_role == $role_name) {
                return $next($request);
            }
        }
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors('You do not have the required permission');

    }
}
```

Notice the ...$permitted_roles

```
Route::get('admin/profile', ['middleware' => 'PermissionMiddleware:Admin,Marketing', function()
{

}]);
```

You can now specify as many roles as required for one middleware rather than creating multiple by using middleware parameters

Docs
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#middleware-parameters

Comment: Get this error: Class AdminMiddleware does not exist

Comment: Answer is correct just plz fix this : 'middleware' => 'AdminMiddleware', it should be 'middleware' => 'admin',

Comment: If you know answer plz help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062680/middleware-how-to-redirect-after-check-laravel-5

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume you have a column in your users table with `isAdmin` name which has a default value of 0 (false)

You can give special access using middleware in laravel like you give access to logged in users using `auth` middleware in laravel.
Now you need to create a middleware using the command :

```
php artisan make:middleware AdminMiddleware
```

In your Kernel.php you need to add this line to `protected $routeMiddleware`

```
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
```

In your middleware folder you have the `AdminMiddleware` file.
In that you need to put your logic
In this case this is how it might look like depending upon you

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RoleMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if(Auth::user()->isAdmin == '1') // is an admin
        {
            return $next($request); // pass the admin
        }

        return redirect('/'); // not admin. redirect whereever you like

    }
}
```

Now in your route you have to pass the url using this middleware
Here is how it might look like

```
Route::get('/iamanadmin', ['middleware' => 'admin', function() {
    return view('iamanadmin');
}]);
```

Comment: False should be represented with a 0... 1 is True

Comment: @ColinStadig Thanks fr the correction. It's corrected.

Answer (score 0):

use middleware and check for admin user.

```
Route::get('admin', ['middleware' => 'checkadmin', function()
{

}]);
```

now create middleware and validate admin user.

Comment: How to do that? Any tut?\

Comment: If you know answer plz help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062680/middleware-how-to-redirect-after-check-laravel-5