# Middleware, how to redirect after check Laravel 5

Tags: php, redirect, routes, laravel-5

I need after check if user is logged as editor, to redirect to profile page...

Here is my code:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

use Closure;

class AdminMiddleware {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            if (Auth::user()->roles->toArray()[0]['role'] == 'editor'){
                return redirect('/profile');
            }
                return $next($request);
            }
            else { 
                return $next($request);
            }
        }
    }
```

Problem with this code is when user is editor I get infinite loop....

Here is my routs:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){

    Route::get('home', ['middleware' => 'admin', function()
        {
        return view('home');
        }]);
    Route::get('profile', array(
       'as' => 'profile',
       'uses' => 'UserController@getProfile'
    ));


});
```

Anyone know what is problem?

Comment: of course, if your '/profile' route uses the same middleware then it will keep redirecting to itself. Considering your routing structure.

Comment: Please posts your routes

Comment: Added.... There are two routes for auth users...

Comment: Where did you register your middleware in App\Http\Kernel? Under protected $middleware = [] or protected $routeMiddleware = [] ? If you registered it in $middleware it will run on each very request thereby causing infinite loop, so if so use only $routeMiddleware

Comment: Great! Digitlimit thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Where did you register your middleware in `App\Http\Kernel`?

Is it in protected `$middleware = []` or `protected $routeMiddleware = []` ?

If registered in `$middleware` it will run on each very request thereby causing infinite loop, if so use only `$routeMiddleware`

Comment: Having the same issue and this did not solve it, middleware is in $routeMiddleware already not $middleware.

Comment: Let me see your middleware and kernel

Comment: I cannot see any issue with your kernel and middlewares as they are untouched. The problem is probably from your routes. let me also see your routes

Comment: Done. Updated the link to include my routes, please check it again for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73143/discussion-between-digitlimit-and-user3718908).

Comment: You are getting redirection loops because you have $this->middleware('guest');  in your HomeController __construct() and You redirect to HomeController@index() after authentication

Comment: @Digitlimit.i am facing one problem.can you check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132473/middleware-not-working-in-laravel-5-1

Answer (score 3):

I found this to be a less code and less decisions for redirecting users based on roles, Put this in your AuthController.php

```
protected function authenticated( $user)
{

    if($user->user_group == '0') {
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }

    return redirect('my-account');
}
```

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-best-to-redirect-admins-from-users-after-login-authentication

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Kernel.php`. It's in `app\http`.
Try to find  `protected $routeMiddleware`
in that array you need to add this

```
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class
```

After that it should work fine.
Hope this helps anyone who faces the same problem.