# Middleware not working in laravel

Tags: php

I was working on laravel middleware but after log in it return blank page. Following is my code:

route.php

```
Route::get('/','UsersController@login');
Route::post('dashboard','UsersController@dashboard');
Route::get('admin', ['middleware' => 'admin', function()
{

            Route::get('add-post-new', function () {return view('a.addPost');});

            Route::post('/add-post-new','PostsController@addPost');

            Route::get('/all-post', function () {return view('a.all_post'); });

}
```

After login, it return to `add-post-new` page. But it's blank page. Can any one tell where I am doing wrong. Thank you.

**Updated**

user controller

```
public function dashboard()
    {
        $rules = array('email'=> 'required|email', 'password' => 'required');
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

            if ($validator->fails()) 
            {
                $messages = $validator->messages();
                    return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($validator);
            }

            $email=Input::get('email');
            $password=Input::get('password');

            if (Auth::attempt(['email' =>$email, 'password' => $password])) 
            {

                return redirect()->intended('admin/add-post-new');

            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect::guest('login')->with('loginFail','Login UnSuccessful !');
            }


    }
```

login

```
 @extends('master')

 @section('content')

 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6">
    @if(Session::get('message'))
        <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            <strong>{{ Session::get('message') }}</strong>
        </div>
    @endif
    @if(Session::get('loginFail'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            <strong>{{ Session::get('loginFail') }}</strong>
        </div>
    @endif

     <form method="POST" action="dashboard" >
        <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('email')) has-error @endif">
            <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" name="email">
             @if ($errors->has('email'))  <div class="register-errors">  {{ $errors->first('email') }}</div> @endif
        </div>
        <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('password')) has-error @endif">
            <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" name="password">
             @if ($errors->has('password'))  <div class="register-errors">  {{ $errors->first('password') }}</div> @endif
        </div>



        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        {!! Form::token(); !!}
    </form>

 </div>

 </div>





    @stop
```

**Update 2**

This is created new project name of the project final.base URL

```
localhost/final/public

Route::group('admin',['middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('add-post-new', function () {

        //dd('something');
        return view('a.addPost');

            });

            Route::post('/add-post-new','PostsController@addPost');

            Route::get('/all-post', function () {return view('a.all_post'); });

            Route::get('/add-category', function () { return view('a.addCategory');});

            Route::post('/add-category','CategorysController@addCategory');

});
```

Then it throw following error:

```
ErrorException in Router.php line 343:
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Routing\Router::group() must be of the type array, string given, called in D:\xampp\htdocs\final\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 216 and defined
```

If my route group is following:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('add-post-new', function () {

        //dd('something');
        return view('a.addPost');

            });

            Route::post('/add-post-new','PostsController@addPost');

            Route::get('/all-post', function () {return view('a.all_post'); });

            Route::get('/add-category', function () { return view('a.addCategory');});

            Route::post('/add-category','CategorysController@addCategory');

});
```

Then if my url is
http://localhost/final/public/admin/add-post-new, error will be:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 143:
```

If I run without admin in URL like  http://localhost/final/public/add-post-new then it shows `add-post-new page`

Comment: Are you trying to protect routes using middleware?

Comment: @Sid.yes.i am doing for mutliple user.but here i just doing for admin.after login then it must redirect to  admin/some routes

Comment: @Sid.after login it redirect to  localhost/laravel-news/public/admin/add-post-new but it return blank page

Comment: use group for middleware, it would solve the problem.as   Route::group(['middleware'=>'admin'],function(){ //lists your routes here. });

Comment: @Muhammad Sadiq.nope same problem

Comment: Try this: replace this in your middleware    return view('login');  with this:   return redirect('loginRoute');
-replace loginRoute with route uri for login page.

Comment: @MuhammadSadiq.not working. i will try with new project if it works then i wil inform

Comment: @tester This might not be issue with your middleware. Can you do dd('Am inside'); in your `PostsController@addPost` just to see if it prints `Am Inside`? Your middleware looks okay to me. looks more like `view` issue

Comment: @ Digitlimit.if i remove middleware admin in route then it works fine for me.

Comment: Okay, change your middleware from after to before like so and try again: `if(!Auth::check())
         {
            return view('login');
         }

        return $next($request);`

Comment: @Digitlimit.i have created fresh project .after login redirect to http://localhost/final/public/admin/add-post-new.but now it shows error NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 143:

Comment: you had to create new project? what is the base URL of your project? localhost/final/public ?

Comment: @Digitlimit. ihave updated second time my question

Comment: i have created new project .folder name final

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87561/discussion-between-tester-and-digitlimit).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87567/discussion-between-tester-and-digitlimit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you definitely need a route group, as you are currently including routes inside another route which would not work. Change your routes to this

```
Route::get('/','UsersController@login');
Route::post('dashboard',['as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'UsersController@dashboard']);
Route::group( ['middleware' => 'admin'], function()
{

    Route::get('add-post-new',
        ['as' => 'admin.add-post-new', function () {
                return view('a.addPost');
            }]);

    Route::post('/submit-post-new','PostsController@addPost');

    Route::get('/all-post', function () {
            return view('a.all_post'); 
        });

});
```

IT also appears that the intended route wouldn't work as it isn't a named route.

```
public function dashboard()
    {
        $rules = array('email'=> 'required|email', 'password' => 'required');
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

            if ($validator->fails()) 
            {
                $messages = $validator->messages();
                    return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($validator);
            }

            $email=Input::get('email');
            $password=Input::get('password');

            if (Auth::attempt(['email' =>$email, 'password' => $password])) 
            {

                return redirect()->intended('admin.add-post-new');

            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect::guest('login')->with('loginFail','Login UnSuccessful !');
            }


    }
```

It looks like your form isn't going anywhere also try

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('dashboard') }}" >
        <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('email')) has-error @endif">
            <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" name="email">
             @if ($errors->has('email'))  <div class="register-errors">  {{ $errors->first('email') }}</div> @endif
        </div>
        <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('password')) has-error @endif">
            <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" name="password">
             @if ($errors->has('password'))  <div class="register-errors">  {{ $errors->first('password') }}</div> @endif
        </div>



        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        {!! Form::token(); !!}
    </form>
```

Comment: .i have added your code but now it return login page also blank

Comment: Also change the get for the add post new as they are the same. Ill make the adjustments in the code above

Comment: yes debug is true.'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),

Comment: Is it set to true in your env file?

Comment: yes .APP_DEBUG=true.even i tried your updated code but doesnt work

Comment: strange, okay and I presume without the route group and filter it works fine

Comment: i am trying to solve this from two days.i dont know why this is happening.even i watched laracat 5.1 video tutorial but no use for me

Comment: so if you delete the group you still get a white screen?

Comment: @if i change group to get in your code then it retun login page also blank.suppose i use my code as per my question then login page will display but after successful pages all  blank\

Comment: Did you add use Auth; at the top of your AdminMiddleware

Comment: Okay, post your code for your form as well. I will start a new laravel project and see if I can replicate your error

Comment: i will try once in new project .if it doesnt work then i will inform you

Comment: No I mean I will try a new project for you, and then should be able to see where the errors are, if you could just show me your code for your form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87554/discussion-between-chris-townsend-and-tester).

Answer (score 1):

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin']], function () {
       Route::get('add-post-new', function () {
        return view('a.addPost');
       });

       Route::post('/add-post-new','PostsController@addPost');

       Route::get('all-post', function () {
         return view('a.all_post'); 
       }); 
    });
```

you might want to user `Route::group` . Try like this once and see what happens

Comment: if i change to group then  also return blank page .i tried using php artisan cache:clear also but no use

Comment: @tester can you post the controller where you are validating the user login

Comment: try moving this route `Route::get('add-post-new', function () {return view('a.addPost');});` out of your admin auth route and navigate to it to narrow and Isolate the problem

Comment: it s in our middlware admin.

Comment: @mdamia.if i remove middleware admin group then i can see my home page means add-post-new.if i add inside middleware then it return blank page

Comment: after `auth::Attempt` var_dump('allowed') and vardump('not-allowed') for auth success and auth fail respectively. let me know what you get.