# laravel5 Authentication

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am going to build a My Task project using **laravel5** and here when a user logs in for the first time, he will be redirected to complete your profile page and if the user is logging in for next time, he will be redirected to his profile page.so any body, who knows this , kindly provide the solution of it.Thank you.

Comment: I know many people who can do this. Head over to upwork and you will find me there too. Hope it helps

Comment: SO is not a freelance coding service. You should do some research and try yourself before asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a code in your AuthController, check there a status of user profile and redirect the user based on status.

You can create middleware through which all redirection will happen and add status condition there to redirect.

You can also refer this url on same topic - [Middleware, how to redirect after check Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062680/middleware-how-to-redirect-after-check-laravel-5)

Answer (score 0):

For authentication laravel you can do

```
 public function authenticate()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]))
        {
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }
```

in the `AuthController` controller module of your project.
For other ways of authentication you can visit to  https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication

Comment: can i put condition that Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])== 1

Comment: no you cant do like that. because  if `(Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]))` its self check the contion whether it is true or false