# how to create multiple login authentication?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

How to create login for different users like admin,users and managers to redirect to different dashboards .

I read about middleware in laravel documentation but didnt got how to do.

i referred  following link

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#registering-middleware

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#protecting-routes

Please help me.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a middleware for your route.

Use php artisan make:middleware AdminMiddleware.
You will find in your middleware folder a new file with this name.

Put your logic in your middleware e.g

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::check())
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
    else
    {
        return view('auth.login')->withErrors('You are not logged in');
    }

}
```

Once you have done your logic in your middleware, you can either call it in the route or make the middleware apply to all routes.

if you want to add it to all routes go to Kernal.php and add it to the $middleware array e.g

```
protected $middleware = [
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
    'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
    'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
    'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
    'App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware',
];
```

If you want to add it to specific routes only, add it to the $routeMiddleware variable and add the alis to the route. e.g.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
    'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
    'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
    'admin' => 'App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware',
];
```

You can then add it to a route, as a filter e.g.

```
Route::get('admin/profile', ['middleware' => 'admin', function()
{

}]);
```

Note::this answer is given by stackoverflow user @Chris Townsend

Ref::
[Roles with laravel 5, how to allow only admin access to some root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29060925/roles-with-laravel-5-how-to-allow-only-admin-access-to-some-root)

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to provide different login for different users - you can simple login user and then check his role.
Suggest using Zizaco/Confide (https://github.com/Zizaco/confide) for users auth and Zizaco/Entrust (https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/) for roles.

**UPDATE**

as OP doesn't want to use external packages:
route would look like this (for instance):

```
Route::put('post/{id}', ['middleware' => 'role:admin', function ($id) { 
 // 
}]);
```

and in the middleware something to check if the user has a role:

```
if (! $request->user()->hasRole($role)) {
        // whatever
}
```

**UPDATE #2**

Here is tutorial (based on Laravel 5.0 but should work):

http://heera.it/laravel-5-0-acl-using-middleware

Comment: ,thank you for answering .but i need to design without plugin

Comment: ok, so you have to store some roles (Role model) in DB, and then check if current user (User model) has a role (User in relation OneToMany to Role) by knowing that you can easily redirect user to different dashboard

Comment: what do you mean? 'group'?

Comment: suppose admin having index,add,edit  page etc..how to protect them using middleware ?

Comment: `Route::put('post/{id}', ['middleware' => 'role:admin', function ($id) {
    //
}]);` and in your middleware you must check if user has this role. You don't wan't to use external packages so you must invent the wheel again ;-) In entrust it would be as simple as `Entrust::hasRole('Admin')`

Comment: thank you. i will try.can you update that in answer .it might be helpful for others

Comment: @john read the tutorial linked in my answer - it should help you to build your own Access Control List

Answer (score 2):

For Laravel 5.1 Multiple Auth

https://github.com/Kbwebs/MultiAuth

Answer (score 0):

You can use **multiAuth** for multiple authentication types

https://github.com/ollieread/multiauth

**For Laravel 5**

https://github.com/sboo/multiauth

Comment: ,thank you for answering .but i need to design without plugin

Comment: this package is for Laravel 4.2 but OP asked about Laravel 5.1

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve multiple authentication in laravel by using this package

https://packagist.org/packages/sarav/laravel-multiauth

Here I have already answered this question [How to use authentication for multiple tables in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192535/how-to-use-authentication-for-multiple-tables-in-laravel-5/32822341#32822341)

Answer (score 0):

## Answered same question here [multiple login authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49443169/9070934)

Create `Controller` and `Middleware` for multiple useres.
I used this method in my own project it's working.

> You can try this.