# Laravel Authentication for multiple users

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have 4 types of users in my application and details are stored in 4 different tables, so how can I implement Laravel's Authentication?

```
Route::post('/adlogin', 'mainController@adminlogin');
Route::get('/sellerlogin', function () {
    return view('seller.pages.login');
});

Route::post('/sellerlog_in', 'mainController@sellerlogin');
```

Comment: use LoginConteoller and write switch case in it, and also use different middlewares.

Comment: actually what part do you need clarification on .. you want to use laravel user scaffolding for this or you want to make all the three account logins together as one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Use this as your controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

//Use Dependencies
use Auth;

class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{
```

> Middleware used here is `admin` which you have to create in `config/auth.php`

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest:admin', ['except'=>'logout']);
}
```

> Create a view for your admin Login

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('auth.admin_login');
}

public function login(Request $request)
{
    //Validate the Form Data
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'=>'required|email',
        'password'=>'required|min:5'
    ]);

    //Attempt to log the Admin In
    $email= $request->email;
    $password= $request->password;
    $remember= $request->remember;
```

> After Successfully login where you want to redirect like here I am redirecting 
>    to`admin.dashboard`

```
    //If Successful redirect to intended location
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember)) {
        return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
    }

    //If Unsuccessful redirect back to login form with form data
    return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
}

/**
 * Log the Admin out of the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function logout()
{
    Auth::guard('admin')->logout();

    return redirect()->route('admin.login');
}
}
```

> After logout redirect back to login page
>
> ### Make sure you are using right `guard` for right User. Create same functionality for more user types as you want create `guards` for them.

In `config/app.php`

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'admin-api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],
```

As `admin` and `admin-api` created here create for your user types

> Add providers

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],
],
```

At last for resetting passwords use this.

```
'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 10,
        ],
    ],
```

In `http/middleware/redirectIfAuthenticated.php` add this to your `handle` function

```
//Check for admin login guard
        switch ($guard) {
            case 'admin':
                if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                    return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
                }
                break;

            default:
                if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                    return redirect('/dashboard');
                }
                break;
        }
```

You can add more cases for your user types.

### This is all you want to create multi auth. As you created different table for different roles you have to follow this process.

- Create `LoginController` for all user types or use your logic to log them in.
- Add your `guards` for every user type in auth.php
- Add your cases to `RedirectIfAuthenticated`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**laravel-permission**](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) package.This package allows you to manage user permissions and roles in a database.

Comment: Laravel-Permission is for authorization i.e same users different roles not for the different users