# How to protect register with auth midleware in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

l have run the php artisan make:auth command and have the login views..but now my concern is l want to protect users from registering themselves, they should be registered by an authenticated admin how do l use the auth middleware to achieve this .

my routes file is like

```
  Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

  Route::get('/', function () {
return view('login');
 });

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');


});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29060925/roles-with-laravel-5-how-to-allow-only-admin-access-to-some-root

Answer (score 1):

**Solution #1 (any authenticated user)**

On file /app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php

simply change from

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}
```

to

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

**Solution #2 (only authenticated admin user)**
a) run

```
php artisan make:middleware IsAdmin
```

b) Add to the routeMiddleware array in your kernel file by opening app/Http/Kernel.php:

```
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsAdmin::class,
```

c) edit isAdmin file

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
     if (Auth::user() &&  Auth::user()->is_admin == 1) {
            return $next($request);
     }

    return redirect('/');
}
```

d) On file /app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php, change the constructor from

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}
```

to

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('admin');
}
```

e) Update user migration to include de boolean field

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->mediumIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->boolean('is_admin')->default(false);
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

f) Update User model to allow 'is_admin' field

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'is_admin'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

The static method auth() from the Route class is generating the routes for you, so you could just remove the following line:

```
Route::auth();
```

And manually place the routes that you want to have enabled, in your case just the login ones:

```
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

Hope it helps!